# Is it an Arithmetic Sequence or not?

Tags: code-golf, math, number, sequence, decision-problem

## Challenge

In this challenge, the input will be an ordered set of numbers and the program should be able to tell if the set of numbers is an [Arithmetic Sequence](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sequences-sums-arithmetic.html).

## Input

- The input will be a list separated by `,`(comma) or `,` (comma+space).
  The minimum length of the list should be 3 elements.

## Output

- The Output can be a Boolean (True or False),  or a number (1 for True, 0 for False).

## Test cases

```
In: 1, 3, 5
Out: True

In: 1,4, 7
Out: 1

In: 5, 9,10
Out: 0

In: 5,3,1
Out: False
```

## Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code by bytes wins.
- The input will be finite

Best of Luck

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf Stack Exchange. Nice challenge. It is highly recommended to allow input and output by our [default rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/43319), instead of having arbitrary restrictions like prohibiting functions. Some languages only have functions.

Comment: It is also highly recommended to provide some test cases.

Comment: Will the input have a minimum of 2 elements.

Comment: You say "a set of numbers". Does that mean they might not be in order?

Comment: "..... (also, if this isn't valid, the Mathematica answer isn't either)" . @mypronounismonicareinstate you are funny!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to clarify a few things. As already pointed out by @Adám, please consider using our [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/43319) in your future challenges. Unless that's the whole point of the challenge, parsing the input and/or formatting the output is just a useless annoyance. Also, there's no such thing as "an ordered set" as a set has no order by definition.

Comment: "- This **can** also run on an infinity loop.". What does that mean?

Comment: @pppery That the user should endlessly give a set of numbers.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand you. Are you saying "the input must be finite"?

Comment: @pppery Yes exactly!

Comment: Why is `5,3,1` false?

Comment: I'm still confused by all the mention of "set". The input `1,3,2` should be `False`, right? Can all the "set" be changed to "list"?

Comment: @xnor I edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: So, the last thing to clarify is why `5,3,1` is false.

Comment: I hope this question gets re-opened, my intended-to-post solutions: [85 bytes](https://tio.run/##bc1LCsIwFIXhuasIGSV4CkmTKoguoBNX4KRqihf6sklLcfOxFUEocmffD@dSG0t2OLFLrF14tHcxQeQzTMx3FQXBwWVddKLw56G@ul5KX9HNCYVEfwJhxJjkrAiCtlrKoaHn4JinlzumMpaCa6QwsMi4ZF1PTaiazcIKqYJRsAqZWjV8b83L0rz1jy3Mmi32mN9oA737tfgG) and [84 bytes](https://tio.run/##bc1NCsIwFATgvacIWSUwYtKkFkQP0I0ncFM1xQf9s0lL8fKxFUEo8lbzDcyjNpbscGKXWLvwaO9igshnmJjvKgqCg8u66EThz0N9db38pBEEQducldT7IHej9BXdnNByaOg5OObp5Y6JjKXgGgkMLFIuWddTE6pms7BComAUrEKqVh2@t@Zlad76xxZmzRYZ5jfaQO9/XXwD).

Comment: I would like to re-open this, but I don't understand why `5,3,1` is false

Comment: @JoKing because 5,3,1 is an unordered set of numbers. In the question I said an ordered set of numbers.

Comment: When you say ordered/unordered set, do you actually mean ascending vs not ascending list? Because `5,3,1` *is* an arithmetic sequence, with a difference of `-2`. Either you should specify that this will not be an input, or you should rephrase the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
ê│▀£┴
```

Input `,`-delimited; outputs `1`/`0` for truthy/falsey respectively.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///wqkdTmh5Nazi0@NGULf//G@qY6JjrGBroGBrrGJpxGeoY65gCBSy5gEJGBjrGBjomBiC2hY4ZUKWRDpADJE2AfEMzHWMjHTMTLgOwAFAKAA) (MathGolf is able to execute multiple test cases at once for each line of STDIN input, but feel free to only use a single input if you'd like.)

**Explanation:**

```python
ê      # Read the comma-delimited input-string as integer-list
 │     # Get the forward differences of each overlapping pair in this list
  ▀    # Uniquify these differences
   £   # Pop and push the length to get the amount of unique differences
    ┴  # Check that this length is equal to 1 (1 if 1; 0 if >= 2)
       # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 47 bytes

```
\d+
$*
A`(1+),(?!\1)
(?<=(1+),)\1

^1*(,1*)\1*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JkWbS0WLyzFBw1BbU0fDXjHGUJNLw97GFszXjDHk4ooz1NLQMdQCsrVU/v831DHRMdcxNNAxNNYxNAMA) Only works on nondescending sequences of at least two integers. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
A`(1+),(?!\1)
```

Check that the sequence is ascending.

```
(?<=(1+),)\1
```

Compute the differences after the first value.

```
^1*(,1*)\1*$
```

Check that all of the differences are equal.

Comment: If it only handles non-descending input, then it doesn't handle "a set of numbers" as specified by OP, does it?

Comment: @Adám Well, I wasn't sure what ordering of the set I could assume... I could easily sort the numbers if necessary, it would only cost 7 bytes I think.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 8 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

```apl
1=≢∪2-/⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94L@h7aPORY86Vhnp6j/qmwoS@68ABgVchjpGOsY6JjqmXHARAx0jAx1jAx0TAx1TA4SwDhRyoWoFauZCN8wYAA)

`1=` Is 1 equal to

`≢` the count of

`∪` unique

`2-/` pairwise differences

`⎕` in the evaluated input?

The `⎕` prompts for input and executes it. Luckily, `,` is APL's concatenation functions, so the required input format evaluates to a list. Spaces are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
',¡¥Ë
```

Input `,`-delimited; outputs `1`/`0` for truthy/falsey respectively.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fXefQwkNLD3f//2@oY6JjrmNooGNorGNoBgA) or [verify a few more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn3lf3WdQwsPLT3c/V/nv6GOiY65jqGBjqGxjqEZl6GOsY4pUMCSCyhkZKBjbKBjYgBiW@iYAVUa6QA5QNIEyDc00zE20jEz4TIACwClAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
',¡   '# Split the (implicit) input-string on ","
   ¥   # Get the deltas (forward differences) of each overlapping pair in this list
    Ë  # Check if all differences are equal (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
       # (after which this result is output implicitly)
```

Of course, this would have been **2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)** with default I/O rules by taking a list input: `¥Ë`.